# Book recommendation about Modeling on Mathematical Biology

Tags: book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

I would like to ask if you have a good book to suggest about Mathematical Models for the Dynamics of DNA and Proteins.

Comment: I feel like it would be better to look into biophysics literature. They also use mathematical models.

Comment: @Paichu thanks for the suggestion